# PKCS12 KeyStore problem while migrate from Oracle to IBM

Tags: spring, pkcs#12, ibm-jdk, sslcontext

I'm trying to migrate my spring service from java Oracle 1.8 to IBM 1.8

```java
final KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
ks.load(new FileInputStream(new File(keystore)), "".toCharArray());

final KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(ks, "".toCharArray());
```

getting error from `ks.load: "java.io.IOException: getSecretKey failed: Password is not ASCII"`

when I tried null at load and init: the load passed but the `kmf.init` throws null error. `(KeyStore: KeyStoreSpi: engineGetKey)`

when I tried null at load and `"".toCharArray() at kmf.init`: the load passed the `kmf.init` throws `"Password is not ASCII". (KeyStore: KeyStoreSpi: engineGetKey)`

Additional information:
default security provider : com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE
PKCS12 = PKCS12KeyStoreOracle

I also tried to open the .p12 file using openssl and the
"Enter Import Password:" was just ENTER (empty pass)